I am planning to deploy ML model in Python & Flask using Spyder. However, I cant find app.py and template in the folder
I cant find app.py and template with html in the folder as mentioned by DigitalSreeni in his youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bluclMxiUkA&t=3s at 10.15. In other words, the app.py and template file does not appear as tab in my spyder. Do we create he files ourselves or how?
Not sure what to do
